# 9022 SQL ERROR while executing CREATE DATABASE query through .net code

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2014

When i try to execute CREATE DATABASE query from .net code,

```
"CREATE DATABASE TESTDB_RE ON (NAME=TESTDB_RE_dat, FILENAME='D:\Test.mdf', SIZE=4MB, FILEGROWTH=4MB) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;"
```

I am getting error

> *"Detail=[9022],Msg=[The log can not be initialized because the log files are not fully formatted. Database 'TESTDB' cannot be opened due
> to inaccessible files or insufficient permission" error.*

I checked microsoft documentation for 9022 error but not getting sufficient information for the cause of 9022 error.

Any help would be higly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try creating database inside SQL Server Management Studio and se if you are successful.  A database has two files mdb (database) and ldb (log file).  Make sure you can write to the root folder on the d: drive.

Comment: Add `LOG ON = (NAME=TESTDB_RE_dat_LOGS, FILENAME='D:\Test.ldf')` or something like that